# chart.js with data from sql database not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, ajax

Hello I am trying to create a chart.js line chart through a html site. exporting data from the sql database to data.php works fine.

This is the code for data.php

```
<?php
//setting header to json
header('Content-Type: application/json');

//database
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root123');
define('DB_NAME', 'Value');

//get connection
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);


//query to get data from the table
$query = sprintf("SELECT Accountvalue, Date FROM Accountvalue ORDER by Date");

//execute query
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

//loop through the returned data
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
  $data[] = $row;
}

//free memory associated with result
$result->close();

//close connection
$mysqli->close();

//now print the data
print json_encode($data);
```

This returns the following result:

```
[{"Accountvalue":"10000","Date":"2001-01-01"},{"Accountvalue":"12000","Date":"2001-02-01"},{"Accountvalue":"14000","Date":"2001-03-01"},{"Accountvalue":"12000","Date":"2001-04-01"},{"Accountvalue":"14000","Date":"2001-05-01"},{"Accountvalue":"12000","Date":"2001-06-01"},{"Accountvalue":"14000","Date":"2001-07-01"},{"Accountvalue":"12000","Date":"2001-08-01"},{"Accountvalue":"14000","Date":"2001-09-01"},{"Accountvalue":"12000","Date":"2001-10-01"},{"Accountvalue":"14000","Date":"2001-11-01"},{"Accountvalue":"12000","Date":"2001-12-01"}]
```

Now when I try to import the data through AJAX into my areachart.js no graph is created. When I change the values in JS to fixed values it works just fine.
What am I missing ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/data.php",
    method: "GET",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      var date = [];
      var accountvalue = [];

      for(var i in data) {
        date.push(data[i].date);
        accountvalue.push(data[i].accountvalue);
      }

 var chartdata = {
   labels: date,
   datasets: [{
    label: "Earnings",
    lineTension: 0.3,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 0.05)",
    borderColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
    pointRadius: 3,
    pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
    pointBorderColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
    pointHoverRadius: 3,
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
    pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
    pointHitRadius: 10,
    pointBorderWidth: 2,
    data:  accountvalue
      }], 
  var ctx = $("myAreaChart");
  var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {

  type: 'line',
  data: chartdata, 

  });
```

Comment: try console.log(accountvalue) to see if its have the data you needed

Comment: Hello I changed console.log(data) to console.log(accountvalue) However this also returned a empty chart area